# Bootstrap - Accordion is not working on my .NET Core MVC view

Tags: jquery, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just started trying to make a portfolio in mvc and tried to put an accordion in one of my views to showcase some of my projects however the accordion-items won't open, but when I tried with a Snippet from w3 school, it works just fine.
Here is my layout(excuse me for this mess):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="mainContainer container-fluid position-relative p-0">
        <div class="background">
            <div class="cube"></div>
            <div class="cube"></div>
            <div class="cube"></div>
            <div class="cube"></div>
            <div class="cube"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="front row position-absolute m-0 p-0">
            <div class="col-10 offset-1 p-0 ">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler bg-light" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Portfolio</a>
                            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Acerca de mi</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Technologies">Tecnologías</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Proyects">Proyectos</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="renderBody col-10 offset-1 p-0 mb-3">
                <div class="p-2">
                    <main role="main">
                        @RenderBody()
                    </main>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - Portfolio - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>

        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

my view:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Proyects";
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Proyects</h1>
        <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                        Accordion Item #1
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                        Accordion Item #2
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
                        Accordion Item #3
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world application.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the snippet:

```
<style>
            .accordion {
                background-color: #eee;
                color: #444;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 18px;
                width: 100%;
                border: none;
                text-align: left;
                outline: none;
                font-size: 15px;
                transition: 0.4s;
            }

                .active, .accordion:hover {
                    background-color: #ccc;
                }

            .panel {
                padding: 0 18px;
                display: none;
                background-color: white;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>

        <h2>Accordion</h2>

        <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>

        <script>
            var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                        panel.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        panel.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add `accordion` class to button,and replace `collapse` with `panel`.Also I change `var panel = this.nextElementSibling;` to `var panel = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;`,so that the element will `panel` class will be found.Here is a working demo:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Proyects</h1>
        <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed accordion" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                        Accordion Item #1
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse panel" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed accordion" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                        Accordion Item #2
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse panel" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed accordion" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
                        Accordion Item #3
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse panel" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world application.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .accordion {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

        .active, .accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

    .panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        display: none;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
<script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                //I change var panel = this.nextElementSibling; to var panel = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;,so that the element with panel will be found
                var panel = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
                if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                    panel.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    panel.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

result:
[image]